# change a pointer that I passed inside a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have this piece of code which will (hopefully) become a singly-linked list implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE{
   int d;
   struct NODE *next;
};

int addNode(int n, struct NODE **root);

int main(){

    struct NODE *root = NULL;
    addNode(3, &root);

    printf("%i\n", root->d);    

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int addNode(int n, struct NODE **root){


   if(*root == NULL){
           *root = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
           *root->d = n;
           *root->next = NULL;
           return 0;
   }
}
```

When I run it, I get "request for member 'd' in something not a structure or union" inside the addNode function; same with the 'next' part. If instead I change the function to this:

```
int addNode(int n, struct NODE **root){

struct NODE *temp;

if(*root == NULL){
        *root = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
        temp = *root;
        temp->d = n;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

it works just fine. My question is; why do I have to create temp? As I understand it, in the first version of the code I am passing a pointer to root, so that there should be no 'pass by reference' issues, and it should not have problems running... What's the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(*root)->d = n;
(*root)->next = NULL;
```

Its an operator precedence problem. Using `()` will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence.

```
*root->d = n;
```

is parsed as

```
*(root->d) = n;
```

But you want

```
(*root)->d = n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Operator Precedence Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++). The `->` operator has a higher precedence than the `*` (dereference) operator, which is the reason for your error.

*root->d is interpreted as *(root->d) instead of (*root)->d due to operator precedence.